# RedHat 7: lpadmin can't find HP ppd file?

Tags: rhel, cups, hp-printer

I am trying to add a printer on a RedHat 7.5 system from the command line as follows:

```
/sbin/lpadmin -p printername -v socket://printerfqdn:9100 -m hp-laserjet_3015-ps.ppd.gz -L "Room number goes here" -E
```

This command failed with the following error message:

```
lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.
```

I have HP-related packages installed:

```
hpijs.x86_64                                                                                                                            
hplip.x86_64                                                                                                                            
hplip-common.x86_64                                                                                                                     
hplip-libs.x86_64  
                                                                                                               I found that this error happens because the PPD file that I had specified with `-m ` is located in `/usr/share/ppd/HP` (from the hpijs RPM), but apparently cups only looks in `/usr/share/cups/model`
```

Of course, an easy workaround is to create a link from the expected location to the actual file location, but I'm sure RedHat created this directory structure intentionally.

What is the official way of installing an HP Laserjet 3015 on RedHat 7 from the command line?

Edit:

The command:

```
lpinfo -m | grep 3015
```

shows the following:

`foomatic-db-ppds/Epson/epl6200.ppd.gz EPSON EPL-6200 PS3 v3015.102
foomatic-db-ppds/Epson/epln2500.ppd.gz EPSON EPL-N2500 PS3 v3015.102
foomatic-db-ppds/Epson/epln2550.ppd.gz EPSON EPL-N2550 PS3 v3015.102
foomatic-db-ppds/Epson/epln3000.ppd.gz EPSON EPL-N3000 PS3 v3015.102
foomatic-db-ppds/Epson/epln7000.ppd.gz EPSON EPL-N7000 PS3 v3015.102
gutenprint.5.2://hp-lj_3015/expert HP LaserJet 3015 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9
gutenprint.5.2://hp-lj_3015/simple HP LaserJet 3015 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 Simplified
foomatic:HP-LaserJet_3015-gutenprint-ijs-simplified.5.2.ppd HP LaserJet 3015 Foomatic/gutenprint-ijs-simplified.5.2
foomatic:HP-LaserJet_3015-gutenprint-ijs.5.2.ppd HP LaserJet 3015 Foomatic/gutenprint-ijs.5.2
foomatic:HP-LaserJet_3015-Postscript.ppd HP LaserJet 3015 Foomatic/Postscript
drv:///hp/hpijs.drv/hp-laserjet_3015-hpijs-pcl3.ppd HP LaserJet 3015 hpijs pcl3, 3.15.9
drv:///hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_3015-pcl3.ppd HP LaserJet 3015 pcl3, hpcups 3.15.9
hp-laserjet_3015-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet 3015 Postscript
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_3015-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet 3015 Postscript`

This was taken after I already used the link-workaround described above. Using the analogous command on another HP printer shows this:

`[root@mycomputer ~]# lpinfo -m | grep m1522
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_m1522_mfp-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet M1522 MFP Series Postscript
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_m1522n_mfp-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet M1522 MFP Series Postscript
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_m1522nf_mfp-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet M1522 MFP Series Postscript
drv:///hp/hpijs.drv/hp-laserjet_m1522nf_mfp-hpijs-pcl3.ppd HP LaserJet m1522nf MFP hpijs pcl3, 3.15.9
drv:///hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_m1522nf_mfp-pcl3.ppd HP LaserJet m1522nf MFP pcl3, hpcups 3.15.9`

Comment: does `lpinfo -m | grep 3015` show a URI for that model?

Comment: @thrig Good thought. I'll add that info to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the "full" path from the lpinfo output:

```
/sbin/lpadmin -p printername -v socket://printerfqdn:9100 -m lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_3015-ps.ppd.gz -L "Room number goes here" -E
```